# 4G iPod Touch internet speed incredibly slow with B/G WiFi router but fast with N

Tags: wifi, ipod, network

I have a B/G protocol modem/router and when I connect my iPod Touch (4G) to it, the internet access is incredibly slow (0,19 MB/s DOWN // 0,05 MB/s UP). So I've tried to create a new wifi (N) connection through the share menu on my iMac and connecting to it the iPod Touch has the normal speed one would expect.
I've also tried to restore wifi settings and restore from DFU my iPod but nothing changes.
Any idea on how to make my iPod Touch fast with my B/G modem?
Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of "fast", and why if you can create an N connection would you want the B/G?

Comment: Major question - is the internet as slow on other wireless devices/computers, or just the iPod Touch?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite normal to see a real difference between `802.11b`, `g` and `n` wireless networks.
The maximum network speed you can reach on this 3 different standards are:

```
IEEE     |        max speed        | ratio relative
standard |  radio     |  practical | to 802.11b
---------|------------|------------|---------------
802.11b  |  11 Mbit/s |   5 Mbit/s |   1
802.11g  |  54 Mbit/s |  25 Mbit/s |   5
802.11n  | 270 Mbit/s | 120 Mbit/s |  24
```

On the other hand, `802.11b`, `g` and `n` use different radio channels.
You may consider these channels as different roads with different speed
limits and different amounts of traffic. Some of these channels may be
free when others may be congested.

Your problem isn't a problem, but rather the radiowave reality.
If you want to *see* it and even bring it under control,
I advise you to use [iStumbler](http://istumbler.net/). This is an invaluable tool for wireless network tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your router's wireless channel or it's neighboring channels are occupied by many other wireless networks?
This is one reason a Wireless connection can experience huge slow down's. This would not be the case on an N-network as it operates in another frequency.

Comment: iPod touches only support the 2.4 Ghz band for 802.11n, so it will probably be on the same frequency.